# How to build MacOS app with hardened runtime in AppBundler

Tags: gradle, codesign, notarize

I am using AppBundler plugin in gradle to build my Java app.
Now to have my app notarized, Apple requires the app to be built with 'hardened runtime' option.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following entitlements when signing my app and fixed the problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```