# macOS notarization error: "The signature algorithm used is too weak"

Tags: cocoa, codesign, notarize

I wonder if anyone's familiar with this error which only happens when I upload my apps to Apple for notarization:

```
"AppName.zip/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/EWSMacCompress.tar.gz/EWSMacCompress.tar/EWSMac.framework/Versions/A/EWSMac83886082"
"The signature algorithm used is too weak."
```

Additional info:

-I've been signing my apps for years with no issues. The error only happens when sending the apps for notarization.

-I submitted a bug back in November 2018, provided Apple all the info they asked for - but it was never addressed further.

-I recently contacted Apple again and they pointed me to some resource page that was last updated back in 2016. It briefly mentions a similar error - but still without any info on how to solve it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG301

-A search on this error didn't produce anything useful.

-The tar.gz file in question is an eSellerate licensing framework. As many people may know, it's been a popular licensing platform for Mac software for over a decade. While I switched to a different licensing platform some time ago, I still have thousands of customers with eSellerate licenses (as I'm sure is the situation with many other Mac developers).

As far as I understand, this whole situation has to do something with signing files inside tar.gz archives - on which I couldn't find any info either

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to unpack your `tar`, `zip` or `jar` file, codesign all the files that have errors and repackage them.

Just go through the logs and codesign all of them with errors, and then sign the app as a whole.
For me, I use the following two commands.

```
find ./MyApp -type f \
 -exec codesign --timestamp \
 --keychain /Users/builduser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db \
 -s 'Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXX' -f --verbose=9 --deep \
 --options=runtime --entitlements entitlements.xml {} +
```

and then sign the app

```
codesign --timestamp \
 --keychain /Users/builduser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db \
 -s 'Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXX' -f --verbose=9 --deep \
 --options=runtime --entitlements entitlements.xml MyApp
```

You must run codesign with `--options=runtime`.
Here's a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112078/how-to-upload-dmg-file-for-notarization-in-xcode) to notorization.

If you are building Java apps, these links might also be helpful:
[How to build MacOS app with hardened runtime in AppBundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758815/how-to-build-macos-app-with-hardened-runtime-in-appbundler)

https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/issues/39/build-with-hardened-runtime

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, laocius. All my apps are Cocoa. I'll try to implement your suggestion to unpack-sign-repackage as a Run Script phase in Xcode and report back.

Comment: YES! It worked. Thanks a lot!
That is signing the actual framework - then package it as tar.gz.